# Discrete Math. Basics of counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to arrange 10 colored balls (red, black, blue, green, yellow, white, pink, orange, purple, brown) in a row so that the black ball is not followed immediately by the red ball?

Comment: I'd be inclined to subtract the number of cases in which the black ball *is* followed immediately by the red ball from the total number of ways to arrange the ten balls.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If there is no restriction, how many combinations are there?

If black ball must be followed by a red ball, how many combinations are there?

Your answer to your original question could be in the form of $a!-b!$. Can you figure out the $a$ and $b$?